# How can I create a new thread only if no other threads are currently open?

Tags: java, multithreading

This code creates and starts a thread:

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try { player.play(); }
        catch ( Exception e ) { System.out.println(e); }
    }
}.start();
```

I'd like to modify this code so that the thread only starts if there are no other threads open at the time! If there are I'd like to close them, and start this one.

Comment: (except the main thread, I guess ;) )

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can create an `ExecutorService` that only allows a single thread with the [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29) method.  Once you get the single thread executor, you can call `execute` with a `Runnable` parameter:

```
Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.execute(new Runnable() { public void run() { /* do something */ } });
```

Comment: That's what he wants I thought, only 1 Thread of that type running at any given time.

Comment: Yepp, that's what I want, only 1 thread running at any given time. I only need that thread to play music in the background while i can still execute any operation in the foreground.

Comment: Ok, I was under the impression that you could have a variable number of other threads running, but this music-playing thread could shut them down when necessary.  One problem with this approach is that if the thread currently executing in the executor is taking a long time, your music thread will have to wait for it.

Comment: Unless you stop it manually, in which case I don't see any reason to use an executor in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

My preferred method would be putting a synchronized keyword on the play method

```
synchronized play()
```

synchronized methods will lock the function so only one thread will be allowed to execute them at a time.

Here's some more info
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Answer (score -6):

you could create a static data member for the class(where threading takes place) which is incremented each time an object of that class is called,read that and u get the number of threads started

Comment: that's a good idea, but then how would i close the other threads? i wouldn't have any reference to them