# How to start concurrent threads that acquire a file lock and wait on each other

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io, thread-safety, file-locking

I'm studying the `FileLock` class. What I want to do is start three `Threads` that will run at the same time and access a single file. While the file is locked by one thread, I want the other two threads to wait for their turn when the lock is released. However, when I run my code below, the threads don't even start all at the same time--they are started one after the other, as soon as each of their `run()` methods is finished. I don't understand.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        SomeThread t1 = m.new SomeThread("t1");
        SomeThread t2 = m.new SomeThread("t2");
        SomeThread t3 = m.new SomeThread("t3");
        t1.run();
        t3.run();
        t2.run();
    }

    class SomeThread implements Runnable {
        String name;

        public SomeThread(String s) {
            name = s;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(name + " started!");
            OtherClass.access(name);
        }
    }

    static class OtherClass {
        static File file = new File("testfile.txt");

        public static void access(String name) {
            FileChannel channel = null;
            FileLock lock = null;
            try {
                channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();
                lock = channel.lock();
                System.out.println("locked by " + name);
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (lock != null) {
                    try {
                        lock.release();
                        System.out.println("released by " + name);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (channel != null) {
                    try {
                        channel.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the scenario I'm trying to get at? And why aren't they starting at the same time? I thought the `lock()` method only makes the other threads accessing the same file wait until the lock is released.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Threads are started with `Thread.start`, not `Thread.run`. `run` will just call the `run` method sequentially on the main thread.

You're not even creating threads actually:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main m = new Main();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(m.new SomeThread("t1"));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(m.new SomeThread("t2"));
    Thread t3 = new Thread(m.new SomeThread("t3"));
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
}
```

Comment: Ah, you mean passing the `Runnable` inside a `Thread` object!

Comment: Just for the record, this is going to generate an `OverlappingFileLockException`.

Comment: @mattquiros: This means there is also a problem with `OtherClass` I guess, but now at least you have concurrent threads.

Comment: @mattquiros: The docs of `FileLock` say: `File locks are held on behalf of the entire Java virtual machine. They are not suitable for controlling access to a file by multiple threads within the same virtual machine.` Why don't you just use a normal lock instead?

Answer (score 1):

Forget it. It won't work. File locks are held on behalf of the entire process, not individual threads.

Comment: I guess he could just use a normal lock instead.

Comment: Interesting. Now I don't know how to make `AsyncTasks` reading and writing to the same file coordinate in Android.

Comment: @Tudor What's a normal lock? Something I have to write on my own?

Comment: @mattquiros: All you need is the `ReentrantLock` class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

Comment: @mattquiros It shouldn't be that interesting, or that much of a surprise. It is stated in the Javadoc in almost exactly those terms.